# Raspberry Pi Infinitely asks for WiFi password and won’t connect after switching to ssd

Tags: wifi, pi-4

I have a raspberry Pi 8 GB, running Raspberry Pi OS 12 Bookworm 64 bit. I just switched from the SD card to an SSD as my main storage by using the SD card copier app included in Raspberry Pi OS to duplicate the SD card contents onto the SDD. Now whenever I power the RPi on it automatically tries to connect to the my WiFi and fails, and repeatedly asks me for the WiFi password. Regardless of what network I try to connect to, every time it just asks for the password over and over again. I’ve tried putting the network in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. I’ve tried forgetting anll the connections and reconnecting. The Wi-Fi does work when booting to the SD card, Just not the SSD.

Comment: What OS? How did you switch? You have posted no diagnostics.

Comment: @Milliways I've edited the post to include more relevant information.

Comment: @Milliways I’ve updated again to include the os version, if there’s something else you want please tell me exactly what I’m missing

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why your SD Copy has problems (it always works for me), but without details it is impossible to guess.

Bookworm does NOT use `wpa_supplicant.conf` it uses Network Manager which is normally configured from the network icon.

See [Configuring Networking](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-networking).

Each WiFi network has a separate config file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` with psk (often encoded).

Answer (score 0):

I found a PiOS topic that might point to the issue, looks like maybe the newest Bookworm Raspbian doesn't support all special characters, such as the & I used in my SSID password @ https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=207182 whereas it worked fine in Buster